# "Difference" among Document Term Matrices

Tags: r, tm, corpus, term-document-matrix

Suppose I have a set of `100` documents, `70` speaking of politics and `30` speaking of math (a weird combination, I know that). My goal is to represent them on xy throught methods like the multidimensional scaling analysis, network analyses, som, etc. When I consider the whole set of documents I do like this:

- I produce a corpus (*docs*) with 100 elements;
- from the corpus I create a document term matrix (*dtm*);
- from the dtm I create a matrix of the distances (*dist*) about the terms componing the documents or about the documents themselves (according to what I want to represent).

Obviously I can produce separate graphics for the two, but I'd like to do something different. 
I have three corpuses (*docs_tot*, *docs_P*, *docs_M*) and three document term matrices (*dtm_tot*, *dtm_P*, *dtm_M*).

Solutions:

1) representing the total of the documents on xy coloring differently the politics documents and the math ones. In this way I can see if they represent natural clusters on xy.

2) producing a network analysis on the differences. Is there a conceptual way to subtrack, for example, the *dtm_P* and the *dtm_tot*, knowing that the *dtm_P* has only a subset (70) of the *dtm_tot* documents (100)?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you might consider using a `comparison.cloud()`. Here's an example from the help page of the `wordcloud` package:

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
data(SOTU)
corp <- SOTU
corp <- tm_map(corp, content_transformer(tolower))
corp <- tm_map(corp, removeNumbers)
corp <- tm_map(corp, function(x)removeWords(x,stopwords()))
corp <- tm_map(corp, removePunctuation)
term.matrix <- TermDocumentMatrix(corp)
term.matrix <- as.matrix(term.matrix)
colnames(term.matrix) <- c("SOTU 2010","SOTU 2011")
comparison.cloud(term.matrix,max.words=40,random.order=FALSE)
```

[image]

This also works for more than two groups, as shown, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36055391/4770166).

Hope this helps.

Comment: It isn't exactly what I was looking for but... nevertheless, it's an interesting solution!